# How to get data from big table row by row

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

I need to get all data from mysql table. What I've try so far is:

```
my $query = $connection->prepare("select * from table");
$query->execute();
while (my @row=$query->fetchrow_array)
{
    print format_row(@row);
}
```

but there is always a but...

Table has about 600M rows and apparently all results from query is store in memory after `execute()` command. There is not enough memory for this:(

My question is:

Is there a way to use perl DBI to get data from table row by row?Something like this:

```
my $query = $connection->prepare("select * from table");
while (my @row=$query->fetchrow_array)
{
    #....do stuff
}
```

btw, pagination is to slow:/

Comment: `print format_row(@row)`

Comment: it's known for MySQL that LIMIT with large offset number is indeed slow..  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: Read through https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Speeding%20up%20the%20DBI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> apparently all results from query is store in memory after execute() command

That is the default behaviour of the mysql client library. You can disable it by using the [mysql_use_result attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#mysql_use_result) on the database or statement handle.

Note that the read lock you'll have on the table will be held much longer while all the rows are being streamed to the client code. If that might be a concern you may want to use [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).

Comment: Great! Thank you. That's exactly what I am looking for;)

Answer (score 2):

The [`fetchall_arrayref`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref)
method takes two parameters, the second of which allows you to limit the number of rows fetched from the table at once

The following code reads 1,000 lines from the table at a time and processes each one

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$sth->execute;

while ( my $chunk = $sth->fetchall_arrayref( undef, 1000 ) ) {

    last unless @$chunk;    # Empty array returned at end of table

    for my $row ( @$chunk ) {

        print format_row(@$row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution dosen't resolve memory issue. All data is storr in memory after execute... It is not what I am looking for but still thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Huge Tables I build Data Packages with dynamically built SQL Statements like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id>" . $lastid . " ORDER BY id LIMIT " . $packagesize
```

The Application will dynamically fill in `$lastid` according to each Package it processes.

If `table` has an ID Field `id` it has also an Index built on that Field so that the Performance is quite well.
It also limits Database Load by little rests between each Query.